# Date Showing Up Different in MS Dynamics CRM than that of SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

My string dates are as follows in `YYYYMM` format:

```
201008
201009
201010
201011
201012
...
```

The following is my `CONVERT` statement in my stored procedure:

```
CONVERT (datetime, @FileName + '01', 112)
```

my results are showing up fine in SQL-Server as follows

```
2010-10-01
2010-11-01
2010-12-01
...
```

However, in MS Dynamics CRM they are showing up as the last day a month earlier (corresponding with the previous SQL-Server results) as follows:

```
9/30/2010
10/31/2010
11/30/2010
...
```

What the heck is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always have to remember that CRM stores the dates in UTC, but displays them as the users's timezone:

So for your example, when you're working in SQL the Date Time is in UTC, but when you look at CRM it's in your local time.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the following thread:

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84074c91-4421-4544-83a7-c6eea28a39e9/crm-displays-different-date-than-stored-in-db?forum=crm